# Developing an asset/node based CMS

Tags: content-management-system, assets

I'd like to develop a CMS for fun/personal using asset-based architecture rather than page-based (why, is the purpose of this question), but I can't find much information on the subject. All I've found barely scrapes the surface (there's a good chance I'm searching with the wrong terms).

> An asset-based CMS stores information
>   as blocks of text called assets. These
>   individual assets are then related to
>   each other to automatically build
>   pages.

What are the (dis/)advantages of such a system?

What are the primary principles of asset-based architecture?

What should and shouldn't be an 'asset'? Where can I read more?

Comment: After a quick Google search on asset-based CMS's and architecture, I wasn't impressed with the results either, but it sounds like you could replace the word "asset" with "node" in many cases. If you do, Drupal is indeed a node-based CMS. Also, you should look at Facebook's GraphAPI and the way it is structured, as I would describe its data as "assets" because literally every piece of data is broken down into a JSON-object. And one last thought :) - document-based databases like MongoDB and CouchDB might interest you as well, although they are probably lower-level than you had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Decided to try to answer this after leaving my comment :)

If your definition of "asset" is along the lines of a "node" (such as in Drupal), or a document (such as the JSON-style documents in MongoDB or CouchDB), then here is some info:

I'll use the term "node" for this post. I think it's closest to "asset" and more popularly used. This also might be a very abstract answer, but hopefully it will at least get you thinking and pointed in the right direction.

Node-based architecture, could be described as a cross between neural networking patterns and object-oriented programming. The key is that "nodes" are points of data, and nodes can be connected to each other in some way.

Some architectures will treat nodes much like object-oriented classes, where you have different classes of nodes that can inherit various characteristics of parent nodes - every type of node inherits the basic properties of its parent - an "Essay" node might inherit the properties of a "Text-Document" node, which in turn inherits the properties of the base node. Drupal implements this inheritance model well, although it does not emphasize the connections between nodes in the way that something like Facebook's GraphAPI/Open Graph Protocol does.

This pattern of node-based architecture can be implemented at any level too, and exists in nature - think of social circles within society or ecosystems ;) On a software engineering level, it can take the form of a database, such as how MongoDB simply has nodes of data (which are called documents in that case). These documents can reference other documents, although, like Drupal, Mongo does not emphasize connectedness. Ironically, relational databases like MySQL that are the opposite of document-based databases actually emphasize connectedness more, but that's a discussion for another day. Facebook's GraphAPI that I mentioned above is implemented on a Web-API level. The Open Graph Protocol shapes it. And again, something like Drupal is implemented at the front-end level (although its back-end implements the node pattern on a lower level, of course).

Lastly, node-based architecture is much more flexible than traditional document/page based CMS architecture, but that also means there is a lot more programming and configuring to be done on the side of the developers. A node-based system will end up being far more inter-connected and its components will be integrated with one-another a deeper level, but it can also be more susceptible to breaking because of this deep level of connection - it is less than separated into individual modules. Personally, I see a huge trend where people are moving to become more "node-based" and less "content-based" as people begin to interact with websites more like applications than as electronic magazines as they did in the 90's. Plus, the node-pattern fits well with the increasing emphasis on user-contribution and social browsing because adding *people* and their accounts/profiles to a web site dramatically increases the complexity.

I know you said "asset," so I'll also say that asset emphasizes the data side of the node pattern more, whereas "node" emphasizes the connections between the pieces of data more.

But for further reading, I'd recommend reading up on the architecture of the software I mentioned. You could also check out node.js, JSON, and document-based databases, and GraphAPI's as they seem to fit well with this idea of asset/node-based architecture. I'm sure Wikipedia has some good stuff on these patterns as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could very quickly scale this up using the CakePHP framework.  It uses an MVC pattern and it provides classes called elements that may be inserted into layouts and can load whatever content you want based on the page, user, moon phase, etc.

---

```
<page>
 <element calls methodX>
 <element calls methodY>
 <Default Content relies on Controller Action(view/edit/add/custom)>
 <element calls methodZ>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Eddie, however you might have to be more descriptive as I can't see how that relates to my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be describing a CMS backed up by a content repository.

The repository itself is implemented by Apache Jackrabbit based on [JSR 170](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=170):

*The API should be a standard, implementation independent, way to access content bi-directionally on a granular level within a content repository. A Content Repository is a high-level information management system that is a superset of traditional data repositories. A content repository implements "content services" such as: author based versioning, full textual searching, fine grained access control, content categorization and content event monitoring. It is these "content services" that differentiate a Content Repository from a Data Repository.*

For a CMS working on top a content repository, look at Nuxeo.